# Does anyone know how to make an encrypted password system in python?

Tags: python-3.x, authentication

I can make ones which write to files just fine but I need to make one which is encrypted do not mind to much what module it uses.

Comment: I suggest giving more details of what you mean by the vague "password system". If you speak of a password database, there's `keepassc`, which is a pure python reimplementation of keepass. It's dependencies may be relevant for what you seek to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `werkzeug`.

```
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

secure_password = generate_password_hash('super-secret-password')

assert(check_password_hash(secure_password, 'super-secret-password'))
```